# Spring scoped proxy and custom authorization issue

Tags: java, spring, proxy, authorization, aop

This custom Spring Security method works just fine without using aop:scoped-proxy. Which i'm trying to  use with user bean "user" in order to have session specific instance of it.

If i user aop:scoped-proxy the method loadUserByUserName won't work as expected. No exception thrown. It just somehow skips invoking user setter methods and skips sysouts that go after it. And as a result it fails authorization.
I suspect something is happening with the proxy object that has been created for my user bean. If debugged, just before setting a value of username it goes to org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy object... And then fails authorization.

P.S. I've also tried both parameters for proxy-target-class attribute ("false" and "true"),  the code listed here is for "false" one

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    System.out.println("Username: " + username);
    UserEntity userEntity = userJpaDao.fetchUserByUsername(username);

    if(userEntity == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Error: User doesn't exist!");
    }
    else {

        user.setUsername(userEntity.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(userEntity.getPassword());
        user.setFirstName(userEntity.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(userEntity.getLastName());

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for(GrantedAuthorityEntity gae: userEntity.getAuthorities()) {
            GrantedAuthority ga = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(gae.getAuthority());
            authorities.add(ga);
        }

        user.setAuthorities(authorities);
        System.out.println("lastname: " + user.getLastName());
        System.out.println("auth size: " + (user.getAuthorities()).size());     

        return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
    }
}
```

> **Config:**

```
<bean id="homeController" class="org.sokol.webapp.controller.HomeController">
    <property name="user" ref="baseUserBean"/>
    <property name="userService" ref="userService"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="baseUserBean" class="org.sokol.webapp.beans.UserBean" scope="session">
     <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="userJpaDao" class="org.sokol.webapp.service.UserJpaDao"/>

<bean id="userService" class="org.sokol.webapp.service.UserService">
    <property name="userJpaDao" ref="userJpaDao"/>
    <property name="user" ref="baseUserBean"/>
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>  
</bean>


<mvc:annotation-driven />


<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />    


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

> **Security-config:**

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
    <security:form-login 
        login-page="/"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfail" 
        default-target-url="/userprofile"/>
    <security:logout 
        logout-url="/logout"
        logout-success-url="/"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/userprofile" access="ROLE_USER"/>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/> 

<bean id="webexpressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler" />
```

> **web.xml**

```
 <context-param> 
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/webapp-mvc-servlet.xml
            /WEB-INF/datasource-config.xml
            /WEB-INF/security-config.xml
        </param-value> 
</context-param> 

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>webapp-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>

    </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>webapp-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: please post your config as well

Comment: Added the config. I also have separate config for data source but i believe it has nothing to do with this problem.